# Which uGrockIT RFID SDK(s) for iOS and Android

Tags: java, codenameone, nfc, rfid

Which [uGrockIT](http://www.ugrokit.com) RFID [SDK](https://dev.ugrokit.com/tools.html) is recommended for a CodenameOne app for both iOS and Android devices?

Should I use the Cordova SDK, or is it possible to bind to the device-specific SDKs via native interfaces?

Answer (score 0):

I looked at this and while it might not be trivial I'd use the native Android/iOS SDKs both of which look reasonable enough to add.

The Android SDK is just an AAR file. Just place it in the `native/android` directory without the other changes they're asking for. It would work. You can then use the native Android source code to invoke the features of the AAR.

The iOS SDK has a static lib file. Place it in the native/ios directory with the headers for it. This should work in the same way as the Android version.